# how to separate into separate components

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I am trying to output the first and the second to separate files, but it does not work due to the presence of a hook useTranslation,

**how do i output the first and second to separate components?**

```
export const Admin: FunctionComponent = () => {
    const { t } = useTranslation(['adminPage', 'button']);

    const first = [
        <Resource
            options={{label: t('adminPage:dashboard')}}
            name='dashboard'
            list={first}
        />,
    ];

    const second = [
        <Resource
            options={{label: t('adminPage:dashboard')}}
            name='dashboard'
            list={second}
        />,
    ]

    const getResources = (roles: TRoles) => {
        const resources = [
            ...first,
            ...second
        ];
        return Promise.resolve(resources);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <ReactAdmin
                authProvider={authProvider}
                loginPage={AdminSignIn}
                dataProvider={dataProvider}
                logoutButton={() => <AdminLogoutButton>{t('button:logout')}</AdminLogoutButton>}
                history={history}
                theme={theme}
            >
                {getResources}
            </ReactAdmin>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: Where does the useTranslation hook come from? Why don't you use react-admin's built-in i18n layer?

Comment: @FrancoisZaninotto in projecyt it wos be , i don't try combine i18n and useTranslation , i dont use before international ) and now don't know how do it )) as I understand it, I’ll need to study this topic , and then all will be norm?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: @FrancoisZaninotto , i am sorry , my english is low level, all normal thanks for answer